# Loading files to Documents : Standard object

Tags: apex, visualforce, data-loader, etl

Loaded some external files in to the sandbox using dataloader.
Specified the path of the file in the Body column.
The documents got loaded successfully.
I have tried the same from one datastage job.
But its throwing an error, **since the Body field is of type Binary and file path is a String.**

What could be the possible reasons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Apex Data Loader uses some "magic" during the the data transformation phase. At some point before the process starts, a DescribeSObject call is made to determine the data types of all fields on the object. It uses this data to determine how to transform the input data (which is *always* a string to start with) into an appropriate data type for the field. In this case, it notices that Body is a Blob data type, and checks to see if the input value in the CSV for the mapped field is a file path, and if so, automatically loads that file into the field encoded as a Blob. I'm not familiar with DataStage, but it sounds like using file paths are not supported. You may want to contact the support team for DataStage directly and ask them if using file paths are supported, and if so, how you'd go about doing it. Alternatively, you may be able to base-64 encode the data and put it directly into the CSV file.

Comment: thanks for the update is there anything that can be done more for the functionality working , In the ETL tool the error that is coming is "Body field has different data type than the data type defined in Salesforce ". Document are getting created but with garbage files. The error is coming from the ETL

Comment: Is there any way to enable salesforce to do the conversion, in case if we are loading the Documents through the ETL?

Comment: Contact their support. If their tool isn't working right, then it's broken, which salesforce can't fix.

Comment: Is there a work around available, if we try setting the Body field with the path of the file, through apex??
@sfdcfox :)